# Best framework for blog management system in Vue

Tags: vue.js, frameworks, content-management-system

I have a task to develop a blogs management system: this system included two role (administrators and readers). 
administrators can access the admin interface to (create, edit and delete blogs). 
readers only access the normal interface to read blogs.
I'm working with Vuejs, so I prefer finding the suitable framework which close with Vue. Do you know the best framework for implementing my task? please share to me?
Thank you so much.

Comment: Asking for libs is off-topic on SO. Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank @EstusFlask for your notification.